# How to lowercase all letter except first letter in TabLayout?

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-tablayout

I want to lowercase all letters but want to keep the first letter in uppercase, I want to achieve this in tabLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="23dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:background="#fff">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my code for tabLayout. I have included the following line but the problem is, its lowercasing all the letters.

```
app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
```

I have also tried to do it programmatically i.e in my SectionsPagerAdapter class that I have for my fragments since I am viewPager in my activity.
Here is my SectionsPagerAdapter Class,

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    return mFragments.get(i);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragments.size();
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String fragTitle) {

    mFragments.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(fragTitle.toLowerCase());

}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
}
```

Also to call it in my working activity(or Fragment), I have used the following code,

```
public void setUpViewPager() {

    SectionsPagerAdapter adapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

    adapter.addFragment(new StudentsFragment(), "Students");

    adapter.addFragment(new ProfessorsFragment(), "Professors");

    adapter.addFragment(new AlumnusFragment(), "Alumnus");

    ViewPager viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.container);

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


}
```

Here I have given the names as "Student, Professors, Alumnus"(All letter are getting uppercased). I want it to be the same when I launch the app. But problem is when I include that one line in my tabLayout to lowercase the letters its also lowercasing the first letter. How can I achieve or overcome this issue?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "when I include that one line in my tabLayout to lowercase the letters its also lowercasing the first letter." – What happens if you remove the `toLowerCase()` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this code snippet will help, try to apply it to your adapter class:

```
    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String fragTitle) {

    mFragments.add(fragment);
    fragTitle = fragTitle.toLowerCase()
    fragTitle = fragTitle.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + fragTitle.substring(1);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(fragTitle);

}
```

Comment: This seems unnecessary. The titles already start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: "But problem is when I include that one line in my tabLayout to lowercase the letters its also lowercasing the first letter. How can I achieve or overcome this issue? Thanks in advance!"...?????  Yes, but with the toLowerCase() method, they become lowercased...

Comment: Right, so why not just remove the `toLowerCase()` call? Starting with a title that has an uppercase first letter, then converting to all lowercase, only to uppercase the first letter again is rather pointless. I'm trying to get clarification from the OP as to why they have that call there to begin with.

Comment: I want to lowercase all letters but want to keep the first letter uppercase.

Comment: @Kaushal Your titles are already in that format. Why are you calling `toLowerCase()` on them at all?

Comment: Because its simply not working don't know what's wrong but problem is all letters are getting uppercased

Comment: @Kaushal That doesn't really make sense. If it's the style that's causing all uppercase, then it shouldn't be "lowercasing the first letter".

Comment: Nice! Have a happy coding!

Comment: @Kaushal That makes absolutely no sense. If this answer works, then just removing the `toLowerCase()` call must work, too, since you already have the titles in the desired format.

Comment: No its not working when I remove toLowerCase() its still keeping all the text in uppercase.

Comment: @Kaushal Then you've not provided a [mcve] of your actual code. Here is the result of the code you've posted here with only `toLowerCase()` removed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZEKU.jpg. I invite anyone to explain exactly why this answer is supposed to fix the provided code, when simply removing `toLowerCase()` does not.